# Please select Payment Method Error?

Tags: magento-1.9, payment

I am using magento1.9.3.2 version,i got an issue in onestep checkout.
Issue is in checkout page selected the payment method and return to home its shown an error message like "Please select Payment Method".. please check below image
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Without select payment method, you can't place the order also you should enable COD for by default selection.

Comment: thanks for reply...i selected payment method ,when i am return to home page its display the above error

Comment: Which payment method you are using?

Comment: paynetz_standard payment method.this is third party payment method